# IJ000455: "Wrong ManagedConnectionFactory sent to allocateConnection" with IBM MQ Resource Adapter 9.2.5.0

Tags: wildfly, ibm-mq, resource-adapter

I configured the IBM MQ resource adapter 9.2.5.0 in Wildfly 20.0.0 as follows:

```
                <resource-adapter id="wmq.jmsra.rar">
                    <archive>
                        wmq.jmsra.rar
                    </archive>
                    <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
                    <connection-definitions>
                        <connection-definition class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl" jndi-name="jms/IBMMQ_CONNECTIONFACTORY" pool-name="ibmmq-connection-definition">
                            <config-property name="hostName">${env.HOSTNAME}</config-property>
                            <config-property name="port">${env.PORT}</config-property>
                            <config-property name="channel">${env.CHANNEL}</config-property>
                            <config-property name="transportType">CLIENT</config-property>
                            <config-property name="queueManager">${env.QUEUE_MANAGER}</config-property>
                        </connection-definition>
                    </connection-definitions>
                </resource-adapter>
```

When using this connection factory to create an MQ connection, I get the following error:

```
MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection
...
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000455: Wrong ManagedConnectionFactory sent to allocateConnection (Pool=com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl@f85b573c, MCF=com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl@f85b573c)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:784) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ConnectionFactoryImpl.createManagedJMSConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:309)
```

Comment: You should accept marks answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[APAR IT37469](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/IT37469) was the starting point here. It addressed some inconsistencies with data types returned by getters for Resource Adapter properties - forcing them to return object types (as required by the Java EE specification) rather than primitives (which many, but not all Application Servers tolerated).

Unfortunately, the fix was incompletely applied to the CD release - so 9.2.5 has the issue reported and as explained very well by Felix Siegrist.

The fix has been corrected for MQ 9.3.0 - see [APAR IT40764](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/IT40764)

Answer (score 1):

In `AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection()` two  `ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl` instances (Pool and MCF) are compared using `equals()`. Even though both instances are in fact the same (hash code f85b573c, so a `==` comparison would return `true`), `equals()` returns `false` i.e. the `equals()` implementation of `com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl` violates the contract for `java.lang.Object.equals()`. It does so, because it compares `Integer` values using `==` instead of `Objects.equals(..., ...)`. The according properties are of type `int` but the used getters return `Integer`. When auto-boxing the `int` values, `Integer.valueOf()` is used internally. This returns new instances with each call for values out of the range [-128...127].

To work around the problem, I had to fall back to version 9.2.4.0 of the IBM MQ resource adapter.

Comment: Are you saying that this is a defect in V9.2.5 of the IBM MQ resource adapter? Have you reported it to IBM?

Comment: Yes, it is a bug in V9.2.5 of the IBM MQ resource adapter. I tried to report it to IBM but did not find a place, where I can do this without having a support contract for IBM MQ. So I posted it here to at least help other developers having the same issue.

Comment: See my answer below.